# How to translate a variant of 'Per aspera ad astra'

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, sentence-translation, motto

How would you translate 'through the will of man to the stars' or 'through the indomitable human spirit to the stars'(more accurately, the latter)? Of course, I'm not looking for a literal translation, just something that captures the same spirit those words convey in English. I would appreciate a translation that is succinct, yet as accurate as possible. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to the site! I assume that by "through" you mean "with the help of" rather than "through the obstacle of". Both would make sense, but the meaning is quite different.

Comment: Good point. Yes, as in 'by the will of man'.

Comment: @guest1922939 Thanks! You'll have easier time commenting and editing your question if you register your account and [merge your accounts](https://latin.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: You might also consider translations of the similar phrase *per angusta ad augusta*.

Answer (score 1):

*Per volentiam* (conscious intent, will), or *Per vim* (force of will, determination, even violent force).

If you want the "of man" you can use *hominis* or *viri* the former being more mankind, the latter being an individual. You'd add this after *volentiam* or *vim*

*ad astra* remains the same.

Ergo: **Per volentiam, ad astra** etc.